# Multi-website server accessible publicly but not locally

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, web-hosting

So I am in charge of a server that is kept in a office setting. The server has Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a Dell PowerEdge R410 with 24 GB of RAM. It's hard-lined into the router which has port-forwarding on it and the domains are pointing to the network's public IP. We're running OpenLiteSpeed server on it to be able to easily manage the sites' settings with E-mail and SSL. The websites are publicly available when you go to the sites, but only one site is able to have an SSL on it at a time. That's another issue for another post though.

Our biggest issue is that the people in the office aren't able to find the website if they're connected to the network. This is a vital part of the sales pitch for these guys, so we need that to be in place.

The problem with split-level DNS is that the two websites are on the same IP. The service is a local ISP in the area and is just a simple business line of internet. I'll be honest in saying that we've gotten as far as we have off this setup alone.

Thank you in advance and if you want extra brownie points, we'd love some insight into why only one SSL will work at a time. If you handle the question and the SSL I'll reach out to you personally and figure out a good way to compensate you that isn't monetarily based.

Comment: For the local access to the website, you need Hairpin NAT support on your router. More info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning. What comes to the SSL issue, we need more details before we can make an educated guess what is wrong. The details include but are not limited to: Operation that was attempted, expected result, and actual result. Also web server configuration is important detail.

Comment: The other option for the local traffic is to use local DNS and point them at the internal IP of the server, not the one resolved externally. I'm not sure I follow from your description what the network architecture is and where the problem lies.